# Return Value Found in UDF Query Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, user-defined-functions

**Big edit to include more details**

We display conferences for attendees to select from. Each conference has a duplicate which is treated as a "waiting list" version. The waitlist ID is stored in its parent record in the field waitListProdID. Certain fields are flagged as well.

Conference records = `isWaitlist = 0`, `waitListProdID = *whatever its waitlist ID is*`
Conference waitlist records = `isWaitList = 1`, `waitListProdID = 0`

Attendees see the waitlist version ONLY on two conditions:

1. When the conference's currentAttendance equals maxAttendance
2. If two people from the attendee's company have already registered with any given conference and currentAttendance < maxAttendance

Waitlist conferences have no attendance cap or per-company limit.

I have been tasked to generate a UDF to deal with the second issue. It should return the conference ID (primary or waitlist). The UDF will receive 3 inputs, and 1 output, with the output being either the passed in conferenceID or its waitlist equivalent.

I'm aware that my UDF syntax is incorrect as I'm more familiar with stored procedure creation, but I tried to make it as close as possible.

```
//This query calls the UDF (build in ColdFusion)
SELECT dt.conferenceID, ec.description, ec.price
FROM (
   SELECT dbo.fnGetConfID(eci.conferenceID, #companyID#, #eventID#) as conferenceID
   FROM tblEventConferences eci
   WHERE eci.eventID = #eventID#
) dt
INNER JOIN tblEventConferences eco ON eci.conferneceID = eco.conferenceID
WHERE eco.eventID = #eventID#
AND eco.currentAttendance < eco.maxAttendance

//The function should return only the correct conferenceID
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetConfID (
    @conferenceID int,
    @companyID varchar(32),
    @eventID int,
) RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count smallint;
    DECLARE @waitListID int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Search only conferences that are not waitlist
    SELECT @count = count(rc.regID), @waitListID = rc.conferenceID
    FROM tblRegistration r
        INNER JOIN tblRegConferences rc ON r.ID = rc.regID
        INNER JOIN tblEventConferences ec ON rc.conferenceID = ec.conferenceID
    WHERE r.eventID = @eventID
    AND r.optfield2 = @companyID
    AND rc.conferenceID = @conferenceID
    AND ec.isWaitList = 0
    AND ec.currentAttendance < ec.maxAttendance
    GROUP BY rc.conferenceID

    --More than 1 person from same company registered for this conference. Return waitlistID
    IF @count > 1
    BEGIN
      SELECT @conferenceIDout = conferenceID
      FROM tblEventConferences
      WHERE conferenceID = @waitListID
    END

    --Company limit not reached. Return conferenceID that was used originally
    IF @count <= 1
    BEGIN
      SET @conferenceIDout = @conferenceID
    END

END
GO
```

Comment: If you show sample data and desired results, we might have some idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: SELECT @@ROWCOUNT <-@@ROWCOUNT will tell you the number of rows affected by the DML operations.

Comment: There are any number of possible scenarios. You assign the result of the query to a parameter and check if it's still null. Or if you want to tell the difference between nulls and no results, assign a dummy parameter and check if the dummy stayed. Or you can just check IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 to see no rows were affected.

Comment: Do you really need to use a scalar function here?

Comment: @Sean, I am not loyal to the scalar but I am new this so I'm sort of trying anything.

Comment: OK well we can help but you have to help us. Look closely at your question. #2 is missing something important, the details. #3 says only pass back a single value. Presumably that value is dependent on something. Read the comment from @GordonLinoff. Without these details we are just guessing.

Comment: I've expanded upon my original post.